# How to select data from mutiple tables in SQL instead of SELECT statements?

Tags: mysql

I have used `SELECT` statements to select data from multiple tables but it takes long time to execute this query.

```
select t.id,
       t.department,
       t.owner,
       t.client,
       (select username from tbl_user u where u.id = t.owner)             as owner_name,
       (select name from tbl_task_catagery c where c.id = t.catagery)     as catagery,
       (select dept_name from tbl_department d where d.id = t.department) as deptname,
       (select name from tbl_task_catagery c where c.id = t.subcatagery)  as subcatagery,
       t.periority,
       t.status,
       t.estimate,
       c.takeaway_name
from tbl_task t,
     tbl_clients c
where c.id = t.client
  and t.status = 0
  and (t.id in (select task_id
                from tbl_task_note tn
                where tn.user_id = '130'
                  and tn.id in (select max(id) 
                                from tbl_task_note tt 
                                where tt.task_id = tn.task_id)))
order by t.id
```

How to do it in an easier way?

Comment: i would you recommend to use join (left or inner)

Comment: Start with something simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may over-simplify your query to:

```
select t.id,
       t.department,
       t.owner,
       t.client,
       (select username from tbl_user u where u.id = t.owner)             as owner_name,
       (select name from tbl_task_catagery c where c.id = t.catagery)     as catagery,
       (select dept_name from tbl_department d where d.id = t.department) as deptname,
       (select name from tbl_task_catagery c where c.id = t.subcatagery)  as subcatagery,
       t.periority,
       t.status,
       t.estimate,
       c.takeaway_name
from tbl_task t
join tbl_clients c on c.id = t.client
where t.status = 0
  and exists (select 1
                from tbl_task_note tn
               where tn.user_id = '130'
                 and t.id = tn.task_id
               order by id desc
               limit 1)
```

Then, you can have indices on `tbl_task(status, client)` and `tbl_clients(id)`. Presumably, `tbl_clients(id)` is the primary key so already have an index over it.

Comment: instead of exists i can use in clause for getting large results. is that correct way of doing?

Comment: In usually takes much longer time than exists clause since through using In clause query keeps running even after a match while exists clause terminate execution after a match hence shortening the time. So always prefer exists over In clause.